# I wish to wrap a DLL in C#

Tags: c#, dll, unmanaged, word-wrap

The System.Windows.Forms.dll

I wish to wrap a few functions in this file in a C# class.

Specifically these: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor(v=vs.110).aspx

But I'm not sure how to get a list of functions. I've tried programs that returned no results. I was wondering if someone could give me 1 and only 1 example?

This, for example, returns an EntryPointNotFoundException

```
[DllImport("System.Windows.Forms.dll")]
public static extern void SetCursor(String s);
```

Comment: http://www.pinvoke.net/search.aspx?search=SetCursor&namespace=[All]

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to enable interop services in order to call into windows functions:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

Then, you simply declare the methods that you want to import as such:

```
[DllImport("winmm.dll")]
public static extern bool PlaySound(string filename,long hmodule, int dword );
```

This creates a "mapping" to the PlaySound method in the unmanaged winmm.dll
The method is created as **static** and the use of the **extern** keywords tells the compilar that the method is external to your class (not running inside it)

Comment: Just edited the post, I get an EntryPointNotFoundException. Also, opening the DLL with dll exporter or depends viewer, does not show anything.

Comment: You will not get IntelliSense are you're used to from C# and managed libraries. You have to explicitly add the method signature to each method that you want to use, you'll find those in the documentation that you linked. Entrypoint not found means that the dll is not in the program path, you may have to tweak that a little.

Answer (score 0):

To get list / search of unmanaged functions you can use

http://www.pinvoke.net

For instance, for `SetCursor` you can call

http://www.pinvoke.net/search.aspx?search=SetCursor&namespace=[All]

E.g. to place cursor at a position provided `SetCursorPos` you can do

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

...

// Wrapper
class CursorNativeMethods {
  [DllImport("User32.dll",
             EntryPoint = "SetCursorPos",
             CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
  [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
  internal static extern Boolean SetCursorPos(Point point);
  ...
  [DllImport("User32.dll",
             EntryPoint = "GetCursorPos",
             CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
  [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
  internal static extern Boolean GetCursorPos([Out] out Point point);
  ...
}

// Your Routine
public static class MyCursor {
  public Point Location {
    get {
      Point pt = new Point(-1, -1); 

      if (CursorNativeMethods.GetCursorPos(out pt))
        return pt;
      else 
        return new Point(-1, -1); 
    } 
    set {
      CursorNativeMethods.SetCursorPos(value);
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Please note, that `System.Windows.Forms.dll` is *managed assembly* (you should not interop with), and `User32.dll` is *unmanaged library*.

Comment: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/17177 I'm trying to recreate that. I'm not sure why he uses Windows.Forms. if I shouldn't?

Comment: @Tristan Patrick Richter: you should not *interop* with `System.Windows.Forms.dll`, but sure can use the assembly as well as any namespace/class etc. of it (e.g. `Windows.Forms`).

Comment: I see. Would you happen to know the best way to freeze a cursor, as is done in MMORPGs where you hold down the right click button and drag it?